# How do I 'merge' a git branch without actually merging it

Tags: git, merge, branch

Sounds like a silly question, so let me explain:

My iOS app project was on branch 'master'. I created a branch called 'iOS 7' and did all my work for the iOS 7 upgrade on that branch. Now I basically want the 'iOS 7' branch to become the master branch, so that I'm back to working on 'master'. I tried merging and there were just way too many conflicts that it wasn't worth the trouble of resolving them. All I care about now is the 'iOS 7' branch, I don't care about the rest.

The obvious solution is to just bin the .git directory and start over with a new repository from where I'm at with 'iOS 7', but I wondered if there was a way to do this within git. Basically, some way to say, "look, this branch is now **the truth**, make it the master branch. Ignore whatever is currently in 'master'"

EDIT: I should add that I'm the only person using this repo, and it only exists locally on my Mac. There is no remote repo.

EDIT 2: As per the answer I accepted, this question is not actually about merging at all, since nothing is being merged, which is why I put 'merge' in quotes. I used the word 'merge' only because that is the term generally used when referring to bringing changes in a branch back to the master. Usually that *would* imply an actual merge, my question is how to *avoid* that merge. The accepted answer does that perfectly (as would several of the other answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No part of what you describe is in any way related to merging. You're the only developer, and you simply want to move a branch, completely discarding its old state? Just delete your `master` branch, and recreate it at the head of your `ios7` branch.

```
# Make sure we're starting from the correct branch
$ git checkout ios7

# Delete the old 'master' pointer
$ git branch -d master

# Create a new 'master', pointing at the current commit
$ git checkout -b master
```

The last command creates a new branch called `master` pointing to the current commit (the head of `ios7`) and then checks it out.

Comment: `git checkout -B master ios7`

Comment: @jthill `ios7` is redundant, the default starting point is the current branch if non is specified.

Comment: So, the explicit `ios7` checkout, the `ios7` in `git checkout ios7`, isn't redundant, but the `ios7` in `git checkout -B master ios7` is?

Comment: @jthill Yes; they're mutually redundant. If you use one, you don't need the other.

Comment: See, that was kinda the point: you can do the whole job in one command.

Comment: @jthill No, you can't. Your command doesn't work if master exists, which it does, according to the question. You ignore the prerequisite to first delete master, which is dependent on not having master checked out. All three of my commands matter, in the order they're written.

Comment: `git checkout -B` does work if `master` already exists (as opposed to `git checkout -b`).

Comment: @nwellnhof True, but the resulting `master` would continue tracking `origin/master` (if it actually existed, which it doesn't in this case). It remains more semantically correct to delete the branch and recreate it.

Answer (score 2):

`master` is just yet another branch name. So you can easily rename your branches:

```
git branch -m master master-old
git branch -m "iOS 7" master
```

Comment: +1 This is a better solution than accepted answer given that all branches exist locally only.

Comment: @ansh0l Why is this "better"? It retains a pointer to a dead branch, meaning that useless objects can never be garbage collected. The question explicitly states that he wants to *discard* the old state; deleting the old branch is the *most* correct way to achieve this.

Comment: @meagar OP says his `iOS app project was on 'master'.` and he has `created branch 'iOS 7' for iOS 7 upgrade.` To me, this means he has original commit history on the master branch, and corresponding to `ios7 updates` on the new branch. Since he hasn't mentioned how he created ios7 branch, assuming that the new branch was checked out from master and preserves the commits of the master branch is an incorrect assumption. (He wouldn't be facing merge issues in first place if he did that - he has not worked on master branch since, and so the branches wouldn't have diverged completely).

Comment: @meagar He also suggests `starting over with a new repository from where he is at with 'iOS 7'`, and thus appears relatively new to git to me. I would hence prefer renaming the branch over deleting it permanently (for the off case of him not completely knowing the consequences of deleting). As for the GC, that's lower preference than information loss. Of course, since he stated that he doesn't care about the old state; deleting the old branch is a *very very valid* solution, but IMO its not the *most* correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Git to automatically favor one side of the merge using the strategy options `ours` or `theirs` (see [Merge Strategies](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_merge_strategies)). In your case, if you are on the `master` branch and want to merge the `iOS 7` branch, do this:

```
git merge --strategy-option=theirs "iOS 7"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on branch `master`:

```
git reset --hard 'iOS 7'
```